# MVC 3 Custom routing from sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on a CMS/Webshop engine with a MVC 3 front-end. I want to be able to define url "aliases" for dynamic content/products runtime, and I want to be able to route this URLs to MVC controller actions.
For example I want to be able to define

> ~/Products/Motherboards/{manufacturer}/{uniqueName}
>   ~/HugeSavings/{uniqueName}
>   ~/Products/{uniqueName}  etc.

to map to the same Display(string uniqueName) controller action in ProductsController. These url patterns are dynamic, even the rules for their order or composition is **NOT DEFINED** at design time, the pattern's rule or pattern's content can change in runtime without restarting the application, they are stored in SQL, but needs to be cached. Each pattern has a target which may be a typical MVC url like

> Products/Display/{uniqueName}

or a direct link like

> `http://somestuff.com/stuff.aspx?name={uniqueName}.

---

Every solution I've found used

```
RegisteredRoutes.Clear(); 
RebuildRoutes();
```

which is horrible, because of this for adding one new pattern for one product (or product category) I have to query the database for thousands of products and their corresponding patterns.

So, can I change routes without clearing or restarting the app? Can I "inject" some logic to routing WITHOUT having to recode the whole "look up the controller and action and parse the parameters" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add routes later.  Just don't `RegisteredRoutes.Clear();` them first.

Comment: If I want to delete the old or modified ones, how can I identify them? By pattern only? Can I add an ID to routes for example? (because patterns can be modified, not only added and removed, and at time of saving I don't neccessarily know the old pattern, but I know the ID of the pattern being saved)

Comment: You can identify routes by Name.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're still intereseted, I just answered a very similar question regarding fully dynamic routing in MVC.

[Multilingual URLs with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874061/multilingual-urls-with-asp-net-mvc/6281611#6281611)

Comment: THanks, but we've finally went a different route, we put an url rewrite modul BEFORE mvc's routing, so I can have any (and many) url point to a specific action even with setting a parameters, so I no longer have to set the routing inside mvc dinamically. Check out my musings at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202682/is-it-possible-to-get-the-controller-and-the-action-not-their-name-based-on-t