# Is it possible to get the controller and the action (NOT THEIR NAME!!) based on the url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have found a dozens of threads about getting the name of the controller and method based on the url, I managed that just as well. Can I get the MethodInfo of the method based on their name automatically from the MVC engine, or do I have to do `Type.GetType("Namespace.Controllers."+cname+"Controller").GetMethod(mname)`? Which is not so nice, since how do I know the namespace in a framework class? How do I know if the default naming patterns are being observed, or is there a different config in use?
 I want to get a "*What Would MVC execute?*" kind of result....
Is it possible?

EDIT: further info:
I have a framework which uses translatable, data-driven urls, and has a custom url rewriting in place. Now it works perfectly when I want to show the url of a news object, I just write `@Url.Content("~/"+@Model.Link)`, and it displays "SomeNewsCategory/SomeNews" instead of "News/29" in the url, without the need to change the RouteTable.Routes dynamically. However in turn there is a problem when I try to write `RedirectToAction("SomeStaticPage","Contact");` into a controller. For that, I need to register a static link in db, have it target  "/SomeStaticPage/Contact", and then write 
`Redirect("~/"+DB.Load(linkid).Link);` and that's just not nice, when I have 30 of these IDs. The web programmer guy in the team started registering "fake urls", which looked like this:

```
public class FakeURL
{
public string Controller;
public string Action;
public int LinkID;
}
```

and then he used it like `Redirect(GetFakeUrl("controller","action"));` which did the trick, but still was not nice. Now it got me thinking, if I apply a `[Link(linkid)]` attribute to each statically linked method, then **override the RedirectToAction method in the base controller**, and when he writes `ReturnToAction("action","controller"`), I'll actually look up the attribute, load the url, etc. But I'm yet to find a way to get the methodInfo based on the names of the controller and the action, or their url.

**EDIT**: I've written the reflection by myself, ***the only thing missing is getting my application's assembly from inside a razor helper***, because the CallingAssembly is the dinamically compiled assembly of the .cshtml, not my WebApplication. Can I somehow get that?

Comment: At what point do you want to do that? Where is your code running?

Comment: @SLaks: I specified some more :)

Comment: Look at the MVC source that was released in 2008: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/03/21/asp-net-mvc-source-code-now-available.aspx.  That's exactly what it does - uses reflection and looks for the controller and action based on the route.

Comment: okay then, please point me to the method where the MVC does this, I'll do the reflectoring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was totally wrong approach. I tried to find the type of the controller based on the name, when instead I had the type all along.

So instead of `@Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")` I'll use `@Url.MyAction((SomeController c)=>c.SomeAction())`, so I won't even have to find the controller.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your edit, you can write `typeof(SomeType).Assembly`, where `SomeType` is any type defined in code in the project (eg, `MvcApplication`, or any model or controller)

<strike>Also, you can write `ControllerContext.Controller.GetType()` (or `ViewContext`) to get the controller type of the current request</strike>  **EDIT** That's not what you're trying to do.